# Substitute pattern with multiline text in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have bash variable:

```
VAR="This is \n what i want"
```

and file with following content:

```
asdf
zxcv
qwer
```

I would like to substitue every occurance of zxcv with value of $VAR (multiline text)

How to do it with awk or sed? 
I tried:

```
sed -i 's/zxcv/'$VAR'/g' filename
sed -i "s/zxcv/$VAR/g" filename
sed -i "s/zxcv/$(VAR)/g" filename
sed -i "s/zxcv/$(($VAR))/g" filename
sed -i "s/zxcv/`echo -n $VAR`/g" filename
```

Comment: SHould the string `\n` remain `\n` in the output or be replaced with a literal newline? Do you want the blank chars around `\n` to remain in the output or be removed? Post the expected output given your posted input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-awk`, you can do this by passing variable's value on command line:

```
var=$'This is \n what i want'

awk -v var="$var" -v w='zxcv' 'n=index($0, w){
$0 = substr($0, 1, n-1) var substr($0, n + length(w))} 1' file
```

```
asdf
This is
 what i want
qwer
```

If search word appears in a separate line (as shown in question) then this command can simplified to this:

```
awk -v var="$var" -v w='zxcv' 'index($0, w)==1{$0 = var} 1' file
```

Comment: That'll fail cryptically if/when `var` contains a `&`, just like any sed solution would (but sed would also fail with `\1`, etc). Use literal strings...

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `sed` as well:

```
$ var="This is \n what i want"
$ sed "s/^zxcv/$var/" file
asdf
This is 
 what i want
qwer
```

The key is using double quotes versus single quotes so the value of `$var` is inserted into the sed replacement string.

(btw, as convention, use lower case in Bash for user variables.)

---

From comments: Ed Morton's version is way better by using string concatenation and only exposing the variable component to shell interpretation:

```
$ sed 's/^zxcv/'"$var"'/' file
```

Use that

Comment: I have `gnu sed` ver: `4.4` and this command gives me `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: Try `sed 's/^zxcv/'"$var"'/'` instead. As written the whole command is exposed to the shell for interpretation instead of just the variable you want expanded. idk if it'll solve the problem or not but using proper quoting is always a good starting point and worth a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting same error with `gsed 's/^zxcv/'"$var"'/' file` as well

Comment: Odd. I'm using GNU sed 4.4 too (in bash 4.4.12(3) on cygwin) and both versions of the quoting work for me (I finally got around to trying it :-) ).

Comment: I see you're using `var=$'foo'` instead of just `var='foo'`. That is the issue - you're passing a variable containing a literal newline to sed while I was passing `\n`.

Comment: It is because you are using C quoting for `var`. Use `var="This is \n what i want"` -- Not `var=$"This is \n what i want"`

Comment: Hmm OP mentions multiline text for `$var` and `var="This is \n what i want"` is not really multiline.